# Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8080/BeginSignup' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy

Tags: angular, typescript, http, go, cors

I am trying to send a fetch POST request to my Golang AppEngine API. However, I am getting a CORS policy error, and I have no idea why. Here is my code:

This is the code calling the API from Angular

```js
private async sendHTTPPut(data: UserInfo, func: string) {
    let requestHeaders = { 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' } as HeadersInit;

    console.log(requestHeaders)

    return await fetch(
        this.endpoint + func,
        {
          method: 'POST',
          headers: requestHeaders,
          body: JSON.stringify(data),
          mode: "cors"
        }
    )
  }
```

This is the server code, that handles the CORS:

```golang
func StartApp() {
    router = mux.NewRouter()

    router.HandleFunc("/", hello)
    router.HandleFunc("/hello", hello)
    router.HandleFunc("/AcceptMember", AcceptMember)
    router.HandleFunc("/CreateTeam", CreateTeam)
    router.HandleFunc("/Leave", Leave)
    router.HandleFunc("/InviteMember", InviteMember)
    router.HandleFunc("/BeginSignup", BeginSignup)
    router.HandleFunc("/ProcessSignup", ProcessSignup)
    router.HandleFunc("/CompleteSignup", CompleteSignup)
    // Scoring
    router.HandleFunc("/GetLocalScore", GetLocalScore)

    allowedOrigins := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string { "* always" })
    allowedHeaders := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string { "Content-Type" })

    if err := http.ListenAndServe(":8080", handlers.CORS(allowedOrigins, allowedHeaders)(router)); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
}
```

This is the request that is sent to the server:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/BeginSignup
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Provisional headers are shown
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.68

PAYLOAD
{member: {phoneNum: "0648503047"},…}
member: {phoneNum: "0648503047"}
score: null
team: {teamName: ".None", teamMembers: ["0648503047"], teamLeader: "0648503047"}
```

This is the response, sent back from the server:

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8080/BeginSignup
Request Method: OPTIONS
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8080
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade
Content-Length: 0
Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2020 20:34:51 GMT
Accept: */*
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
Access-Control-Request-Headers: access-control-allow-origin,content-type
Access-Control-Request-Method: POST
Connection: keep-alive
Host: localhost:8080
Origin: http://localhost:4200
Referer: http://localhost:4200/
Sec-Fetch-Dest: empty
Sec-Fetch-Mode: cors
Sec-Fetch-Site: same-site
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36 Edg/85.0.564.68
```

Comment: `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a response header, not a request header.

Comment: Following what @HereticMonkey said, it means it needs to be define on the server, not on your front-end.

Comment: I’m missing the allow-origin CORS header in your server response. The Access-Control-Request-Method: POST also seems weird considering this is a OPTIONS preflight response..

Comment: I changed it to Options now. Not sure why allow origin is missing? Still having CORS issues

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that you are running angular in dev mode (`ng serve`).
In this case the CORS error comes from angular.

You have to add a proxy.conf.json that has entries for your different endpoints in src:

```
{
    "/api/*": {
        "target": "http://localhost:<your-port>",
        "secure": false,
        "logLevel": "debug"
    }
}
```

And reference this file in your angular.json:

```
"serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "<your-app>:build",
            "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
          },
          ...
        },
```

Comment: My app engine endpoint is "localhost:8080/...". i.e. no "api/"

I have tried both /api/* and just /*. Both are not working. I am using npm start which runs ng serve, yeah.

Comment: /api/* was just part of my example, if it doesn't work with `/` or `/*` there probably is still a server side issue.

Comment: Hmm, and target would be my local golang server, correct? localhost:8080 ?

Also, what could be incorrect on my server side? Must the server send the Access-Control-Allow-Origin still? And if this is in prod on https, will I still get CORS errors?

Comment: The angular proxy config is only needed in dev mode, as it runs its own little web server in this mode. Also your web server needs to provide the CORS headers, as the url of your client app (angular) is different than the one of our server app (go).
In production mode it depends on your setup: If you provide your client from your web server then both share the same url, and you won't have CORS issues. If they are provided from different urls, the CORS issue will come up again.

Comment: So as long as I have the 4 CORS headers getting sent back from my golang server, it should work? Just the headers are required to make CORS work? Do you know anything about the mux router solution I've implemented? I got that off another stackoverflow question